# A way to use provider from `forRootAsync` func to import another module

Tags: nestjs

I am creating a Nest.js module and I wanted to implement `forRootAsync` function for it, which should allow to provide required config from `useFactory` method.
Module I am creating is supposed to be wrapper around BullModule (and possibly other queue solutions depending on passed config).

So I have something like this:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true }),
    MessagingModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => {
        return {
          mode: [configService.get('QUEUE_MODE')],
          connectionUrl: configService.get('QUEUE_URL'),
        };
      },
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And inside of MessagingModule I expect to do something like this:

```
static forRootAsync(options) {
  const providers = [
    {
       provide: 'QUEUE_OPTIONS',
       useFactory: options.useFactory,
       inject: options.inject || [],
     }
  ]

  const imports = [
     {
        BullModule.forRootAsync({
           useFactory: (options) => {
              // do some stuff with those options
              return {
                  // proper config for BullModule
              }
            inject: ['QUEUE_OPTIONS']
           }
        })
     }
  ]

 //rest of module 
}
```

The problem is that no metter how I pass those newly created provider, it seems that it's not yet defined in BullModule.
For now, I would be very happy to just sucesfully inject those options in this way, next step would be to inject them into some module that deciedes to use Bull, SQS or if should instantiate module as producer or consumer. But I won't be able to do this if I can't inject resolved config.

For now I have such workaround:

```
    const resolveInjects = options.inject.map((inject) => {
      return new inject();
    });
    const opts = await options.useFactory(...resolveInjects);
```